# Using Conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

how can i highlight a cell to show that range of cells in a row has no data

I have tried the conditional formatting

eg answer in cell AL, for range = L2 to AK2 using isblank but i cant get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using COUNTA to count the entries in L2:AK2 - if the result is zero (i.e. no data in that row) the cell gets formatted

=COUNTA(L2:AK2)=0